# Particular solution for $\sin(x)y'(x)+y(x)\cos(x)=-\sin(2x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let the ODE $$y'(x)\sin(x)+y(x)\cos(x)=-\sin(2x).$$

I know that a particular solution is of the form $w(x)=A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x)$. When I put it in the equation, I get,

$$-2A\sin(2x)\sin(x)+2B\cos(2x)\sin(x)+A\cos(2x)\cos(x)+B\sin(2x)\cos(x)=-\sin(2x)$$
and thus $$\sin(2x)\Big(-2A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)\Big)+\cos(2x)\Big(2B\sin(x)+A\cos(x)\Big)=-\sin(2x),$$
and get the system
$$\begin{cases}
-2A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=-1\\
2B\sin(x)+A\cos(x)=0.
\end{cases}.$$
How can I do now ?

Comment: Your technique works only for ODE with constant coefficient. You must do the variation of parameters.

Comment: Are you forced to solve the equation that way by an exercise or something? You can just divide both sides by $\sin x$ and solve it like you would any first order linear ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Why use higher-order DE techniques to solve a first order DE? There are a set of techniques for problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can recognize the product rule of differentiation on the left side, $$(\sin(x)y(x))'=\sin(x)y'(x)+\cos(x)y(x),$$ which greatly simplifies the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Without RHS, the solution is

$$y_h=C\frac{1}{\sin(x)}.$$

a particular solution can be of the form

$$y_p=C(x)\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$

with

$$C'(x)=-\sin(2x)$$

$\implies$

$$C(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)$$

and

$$y_p=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Comment: Chose another integration constant to get $C(x)=\frac12(\cos (2x)-1)=-\sin^2x$.